# Трудности при выборе фреймворка для JS-разработчика для создания мобильного приложения

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, ionic, native, flutter

Давно смотрю в эту сторону.

Делаю обзор технологий и примеры **ЛУЧШИХ** фреймворков:

- **PWA** (SW),
- **ВЕБВЬЮ** (IONIC 4.0),
- **ТРАНСПИЛИРУЕМЫЕ** В НАТИВ (RN, NATIVESCRIPT, flutter, kivy, kotlin),
- **НАТИВ** (SWIFT, java).

Для фронтендера на JS есть:

**React Native, Ionic, NativeScrpit**.

И так, от теории к действиям.

*ТРЕБОВАНИЯ К ПРИЛОЖЕНИЮ:*

1) Работник открывает приложение утром и запускает геолокацию (**геофенсинг**);

2) Приложение на фоне следит за его перемещениями;

3) В конце дня работник вырубает приложение и идет домой.

Требования к платформе: пока только **Android** (но не суть);

Нашел готовое решение на **IONIC**:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/

И вроде бы хорошо, Я ЗНАЮ **VUE JS** и могу внедрить в него его, а тем более, недавно вышла новая версия и + завезли свой  **STENCIL**, т.е. можно обойтись и без apache **CORDOVA** (не имел опыта с ним, но он имеет негативные отзывы в сети - по перфомансу в частности).

НО!!! Огорчает тот факт, что это как был **webView**, так им и остается. 
Не видел нормальных приложений от фронтендеров как я (крупные конторы могут себе позволить писать на нативе и им не особо доверяю, по причине того, что много вставок делают на нативе).

Есть еще **NativeScript-vue**, который идеально подходит, по скорости моей разработки на нем (даже онлайн конструктор запилили + результат сразу на мобилке,  за 5 мин, без установки ПО на комп),  но огорчает, что **работа геолокации в фоне - под большим вопросом** + **не популярный**. Знаю, что во всех этих фреймворках есть тема **фоновые задачи**, но вот вопрос к советчикам - кто их применял на практике в связке с геолокацией?....

А **ReactNative** - самый популярный - это понятно, это реакт, который я не знаю, но тоже нет гарантии, что в фоне нормально работать будет (и, как говорил выше, крупные разработчики делают много вставок на нативе, которые я не могу себе пока позволить).

Последнюю неделю стал смотреть в сторону **DART FLUTTER**, говорят, что он лучше всех из этого списка справится с поставленной задачей. А кто-то писал, что надо будет еще натив писать (чтобы в фоне работало).

И эти все неоднозначности меня отпугивают приняться за изучение чего-то одного...

- Хочется еще сразу на будущее, чтобы за границей катировалось, но только **react** катируется, который я так упорно игнорю (т.к. это конкурент **VUE**).

Ах, да, есть же еще **PWA** (service workers), но с 2016 года туда так и ни один браузер не завез **geofencing**, а жаль..

Comment: ДЛя гео в фоне - нуно писать нативку . = https://vk.com/wall-162547112_62?reply=65&thread=63

Comment: Вы определились с тулзой? У меня почти схожая ситуация сегодня, что то посоветуете? Спасибо.

Comment: Стою перед таким же выбором. Вводные прям 1 в  1, относительно react-native, даже аргументация та же (упорно игнорю) :).  Вы на чем остановили свой выбор? Как успехи?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй почитать подробнее про [эту библиотеку для Flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_background_geolocation), она предоставляет возможности фоновой геолокации

Так же у них есть [демо приложение в Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.transistorsoft.flutterbackgroundgeolocationexample)

Comment: Данный ресурс не является ссылкообменником, основное из ссылки должно быть в теле ответа. Пожалуйста, поправте ответ.

Comment: От  transistorsoft я УЖЕ ДАВНО видел реализацию на все вышеприведенные фреймворки.
Вопрос был в практике - есть ли у кого практический опыт на каком либо из фреймворков и как они себя ведут в деле, а не в теории. И, МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ, там какие-то ограничения по праву использования, может потом бабки попросят... На сайте у них что-то указано про покупку было, поэтому оттолкнуло их решение, а других --- просто нету (почему-то) !!!! Монополия...

Answer (score 0):

за основу можно взять React Native а именно react native init т.к. в нем можно в дальнейшем использовать нативные модули хорошее сравнение init и expo есть на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/123753/)